# How to transform number values from array? Using php

Tags: php

I have a website (**site-1**) which import pages from other website (**site-2**).

These pages have an **id** number in site-2 and this number is copied to site-1 when the importing is done. So far so good.

Problem is that the **id** of site-2 are huge, e.g.: 32423201639, 3212450421639,... and the sistem in site-1 is no able to handle them. So I need to make these numbers smaller when the importing is done.

**It is important:**

- to generate unique number values.
- to be bigger than 3000 and smaller than 10000.
- It can not use rand(). If we execute this several time the results must be the same

**UPDATE:** **To keep in mind:**

This importing is done every week, so I need to consider this: Let's say a first importing is done, and then in the second importing ONLY the first array value changes but the others remain then this one will be the only one to be changed and the other will keep the same value as in the first importing.

The first thing I thought was something like this (but the most important is missing):

```
$array_values_site1 = array("12345" , "123456", "1234567", "12345678", "123456789", "1234567890", "12345678901", "123456789012", "1234567890123", "12345678901234", "123456789012345", "1234567890123456");

$array_values_site2 = array();
foreach ($array_values_site1 as &$value) {


    /* here I need to change the value of $value:
    --- to be bigger than 3000 and smaller than 10000.
    --- It can not use rand(). If we execute this several time the results must be the same
    --- to be unique */ 
    $new_value = "....";

    $array_values_site2 [] = $new_value;
}
```

Comment: Does PHP have a rand which takes a seed to produce repeatable results?

Comment: @BillWoodger not sure but I think that rand() will generate a new value every time you run it.

Comment: There a reason to not use simple incremental values 3001,3002,3003, etc...? Also, you will stored array values (in db or file) or you use they only at runtime?

Comment: Why not just set up a primary key on the new table starting the auto increment value at 3000? `ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=3000;`

Comment: @fusion3k yes there is. Let's say a first importing is done, and then in the secondo importing the first array value changes but the others remain the same then your approach will fail. This is an important point, I will add it to the question.

Comment: @Egg that will not change the numbers as I need.

Comment: there is no question in your question.

Comment: Please well explain what kind of numbers you're expecting.

Comment: How about hashing, this reduces a long string to unique short strings and you can re-run as many times as you like with the same results. With [Hashids](http://hashids.org/php/) you can encode to numbers or characters too for even shorter strings (and decode back should you need the original).

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I saw, I needed more than three seconds to correct it :) Thanks.

Comment: Haha, comment removed already :)

Comment: If @Hanky웃Panky answer doesn't resolve your problem, you can save last id in text file, or use the solution suggested by Egg

Comment: @Egg Do I need to install hashids in my server?

Comment: @user54747 I've posted this as an answer with links to the website and github site (github has further documentation). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the comments, hashing the original ID appears best:

```
$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('this is my salt');
$id = $hashids->encode(1);
$original = $hashids->decode($id);
```

To specify a minimum length (not a number, but a length) and characters to use in the result, include a second and third parameter:

```
$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('this is my salt');
$id = $hashids->encode(1, 8, 'abcdefghij1234567890');
$original = $hashids->decode($id);
// $id = '514cdi42';
```

See [hashids.org](http://hashids.org/php/) and [github](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php) for info.